# Disable radiobutton based on previous radiobutton selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

in my html page my user should not be able to choose the same color in the first and the second section. For example if in Color 1 `pink_main` in Color 2 `pink_other` should be disabled and grayed out. This is my code and is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <label> Colore 1</label>
        <div id="showchartcolor">
            <div class="showchartcolor">
                <label for="pink_main"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ff829d;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="pink_main" name="main" value="#ff829d">
            </div>
            <div class="showchartcolor">
                <label for="yellow_main">  <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ffd778;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="yellow_main" name="main" value="#ffd778">
            </div>
                <div class="showchartcolor">
                <label for="green_main">  <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #7dd483;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="green_main" name="main" value="#7dd483">
            </div>

        </div>

       
    <label> Color 2</label>
        <div id="showchartcolor">
            <div class="showchartcolor">
                <label for="pink_other"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ff829d;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="pink_other" name="other" value="#ff829d">
            </div>
            <div class="showchartcolor">
                <label for="yellow_other">  <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ffd778;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="yellow_other" name="other" value="#ffd778">
            </div>            
                <div class="showchartcolor">
                <label for="green_other">  <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #7dd483;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="green_other" name="other" value="#7dd483">
            </div>

        </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
function process(rb) {

   //clearing previos disabled
   for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("other").length; i++) {
       document.getElementsByName("other")[i].disabled = '';
   }
   document.getElementById(rb.id.replace('main','other')).disabled='disabled';
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Example:

```js
var main = document.getElementsByName('main');
var other = document.getElementsByName('other');
main.forEach(m => {
  let mLabel = m.id.split('_')[0];
  m.onchange = function(evt) {
    other.forEach(o => {
      let oLabel = o.id.split('_')[0];
      o.disabled = '';
      if (mLabel == oLabel) {
        o.disabled = 'disabled';
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <label> Colore 1</label>
    <div id="showchartcolor">
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="pink_main"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ff829d;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="pink_main" name="main" value="#ff829d">
      </div>
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="yellow_main"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ffd778;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="yellow_main" name="main" value="#ffd778">
      </div>
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="green_main"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #7dd483;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="green_main" name="main" value="#7dd483">
      </div>

    </div>


    <label> Color 2</label>
    <div id="showchartcolor">
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="pink_other"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ff829d;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="pink_other" name="other" value="#ff829d">
      </div>
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="yellow_other"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ffd778;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="yellow_other" name="other" value="#ffd778">
      </div>
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="green_other"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #7dd483;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="green_other" name="other" value="#7dd483">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second Example:

```js
function disableRadio(r, rIdx, radios) {
  let rLabel = r.id.split('_')[0];
  r.onchange = function(evt) {
    radios.forEach((r2, r2Idx) => {
      let r2Label = r2.id.split('_')[0];
      r2.disabled = '';
      if (rLabel == r2Label) {
        r2.disabled = 'disabled';
      }
    })
  }
}

var main = document.getElementsByName('main');
var other = document.getElementsByName('other');
main.forEach((m, mIdx) => disableRadio(m, mIdx, other))
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <label> Colore 1</label>
    <div id="showchartcolor">
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="pink_main"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ff829d;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="pink_main" name="main" value="#ff829d">
      </div>
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="yellow_main"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ffd778;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="yellow_main" name="main" value="#ffd778">
      </div>
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="green_main"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #7dd483;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="green_main" name="main" value="#7dd483">
      </div>

    </div>


    <label> Color 2</label>
    <div id="showchartcolor">
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="pink_other"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ff829d;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="pink_other" name="other" value="#ff829d">
      </div>
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="yellow_other"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #ffd778;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="yellow_other" name="other" value="#ffd778">
      </div>
      <div class="showchartcolor">
        <label for="green_other"> <i style="font-size: 48px; color: #7dd483;" class="fa fa-square"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="green_other" name="other" value="#7dd483">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PisaPonente if you adding more color in the same two groups then you don't need any change but if you adding more group then you may need to add the group to the code.